# Null reference exception in Android Xamarin (VS 2012)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

Im just trying out Andorid Xamarin in VS 2012. Im doing their Hello World tutorial but I encountered a problem. I have declared my main layout resources in this way:

[image]

In my activity, whenever i try to find the resource through their id, it just returns null.

[image]

Both `aButton` and `aLabel` are null. I dont know what is the cause of this problem. Can you help me please? Thanks.

PS: I am attaching also my resource designer class. My objects are declared there (wink).

[image]

EDIT:
This is the corrected code.
[image]

Comment: Can you post more of you activity's `OnCreate` method?

Comment: ok.. just a minute sir.

Comment: I edited my post, updated the activity class image above to show my whole oncreate method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a call to `SetContentView` in your `OnCreate` method.

```
var layout = LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Id.Main);
SetContentView(layout);
```

The first line creates a new view from the resource Main.axml. The second line sets the content view of the activity so it has something to actually display and hence subsequent calls to `FindViewById<T>()` will be able to find the views.

Comment: ow... i get it now... i declared aButton and aLabel as a child of Main Layout. I cannot use them in other layout (i created a new layout in the oncreate method). Thanks!